# Interpret Caret function for evaluation metrics

Tags: r

I want to try different evaluation metrices of caret package of R.

http://127.0.0.1:15640/library/caret/html/postResample.html

```
classes <- c("class1", "class2")
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(obs =  factor(sample(classes, 50, replace = TRUE)),
                  pred = factor(sample(classes, 50, replace = TRUE)),
                  class1 = runif(50), class2 = runif(50))

defaultSummary(dat, lev = classes)
twoClassSummary(dat, lev = classes)
prSummary(dat, lev = classes)
mnLogLoss(dat, lev = classes)
```

The structure

```
head(dat)

     obs   pred    class1    class2
1 class1 class1 0.6547239 0.6146450
2 class1 class2 0.3531973 0.5571595
3 class2 class1 0.2702601 0.3287773
4 class2 class1 0.9926841 0.4531314
5 class1 class1 0.6334933 0.5004410
6 class2 class1 0.2132081 0.1808664
```

What are the columns 3 and 4. what do the probabilities mean.

Comment: Did you see the example on the `?twoClassSummary` help page? The function expects columns that correspond to the names of your levels that contain the predicted probabilities for each of the classes. That's also described in the "Arguments" section of the help page.

Comment: as both observed and predicted are class 1, then why is class2 probability 0.614